# Deja-Dup "Grant access" Failing on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, deja-dup

I've been trying to run deja-dup backup since I realised it's been a while (811 days) since it last backed up. I've been trying to run it and it keeps getting stuck at the "grant access" window. No matter how much I click it, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this I eventually launched `deja-dup` from the command line and then clicked grant access, then saw this error

```
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox: symbol lookup error: /snap/core20/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE
```

Looks like I was using the snap version of deja-dup which was looking for the snap version of firefox. To get around this I just removed the `snap` version and installed it via `apt`. After that it all worked.

Hope this helps someone else